# 'User' object has no attribute 'get_affected_users'// about foreignkey relation

Tags: python, django

I know what the error means, I have a clue why this is happening. But I don't know how to fix it and achieve my goal. Here's what I'm doing.

Users who posted something need to get notification when some other user posts comment on that something. I was able to do "notifying the person who commented when there's a reply to that comment". So, I thought I would do the same thing for the problem I'm having. But I got the above error. Here's my code.

`models.py` for comment

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyProfile)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True, blank=True, related_name="commented_post")
    @property 
    def get_origin(self):
        return self.path

    @property
    def get_comment(self):
        return self.text

    @property
    def is_child(self):
        if self.parent is not None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_children(self):
        if self.is_child:
            return None
        else:
            return Comment.objects.filter(parent=self)

    def get_affected_users(self):
        """ 
        it needs to be a parent and have children, 
        the children, in effect, are the affected users.
        """
        comment_children = self.get_children()
        if comment_children is not None:
            users = []
            for comment in comment_children:
                if comment.user in users:
                    pass
                else:
                    users.append(comment.user)
            return users
        return None
```

`get_affected_user` function allows which user to get notification. (the person who created the reply shouldn't get notification, the person who got the reply should get notified).

In my `views.py`

```
def comment_create_view(request):

    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment_text = form.cleaned_data['comment']
        if parent_comment is not None:
            # parent comments exists
            new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                path=parent_comment.get_origin, 
                text=comment_text,
                post = post,
                parent=parent_comment
                )
            affected_users = parent_comment.get_affected_users()
            notify.send(
                    MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user), 
                    action=new_comment, 
                    target=parent_comment, 
                    recipient=parent_comment.user,
                    affected_users = affected_users,
                    verb='replied to')
        #the above code gives reply-comment notification makes possible, the below code is the one I'm struggling
        else:
            new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                path=origin_path, 
                text=comment_text,
                post = post
                )
```

This line is causing the problem, probably because I don't have `get_affected_user` function in my Post model, but in comment model I have post field which has a foreignkey with Post. so technically can't I use this function?

```
            affected_users = [post.moderator.get_affected_users()]
            notify.send(
                    MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user), 
                    recipient = MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user), 
                    action=new_comment, 
                    target = new_comment.post,
                    affected_users = affected_users,
                    verb='commented on')
```

I have `get_affected_users` in Comment, and in Comment I have post which has foreignKey relationship with Post and in Post I have moderator. So I thought I could've used `get_affected_users` for `post.moderator`... But I guess not, how do I do it then?

Please excuse me if the question isn't clear. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `moderator.get_affected_users`. I assume `moderator` is a user, and thus has indeed no `get_affected_users()`.

Comment: I have get_affected_users in Comment, and in Comment I have post which is has foreignKey relationship with Post and in Post I have moderator.  so I thought I could've used get_affected_users for post.moderator....but I guess not, how do I do it then?

Comment: I don't know; that depends on what you want exactly. Just get a comment from the post or something: `post.comment.get_affected_users()`, or iterate over all comments in a post. Or create a new function for your post model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that Post.moderator is a FK to MyProfile just the same as Comment.user. Second, I'm going to guess that what you're trying to do is notify the moderator when a new top-level comment is created on a Post object, or a Comment with no `parent` set. In that case, your line should probably just be `affected_users = [post.moderator]`.

Comment: then I get the notification  for the comment I make.